# Java SSL: does a server and client have to have a copy of the same keystore file?

Tags: java, ssl, keystore

im kind of new to this and I was just wondering, in an ssl application, ideally in a real world situation, would the server and client both have copies of the exact same .keystore file, or would this be a security risk. Is there any other way to do this without the client having a copy of the actual keystore file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the client and server do not need the same keystore (and usually they are not the same), although it will work if they are the same.

An SSL connection relies on asymmetric public/private key encryption during the handshaking phase switching to symmetric key encryption once the connection is established.

The basics are:

- the server sends its public key to the client.
- the client responds encrypting a symetric key with the servers public key.
- only the server has the private key needed to decrypt the symetric key, which it does.
- the client and server then use the symetric key to encrypt all the data passed between them.

Like I say that's the basics, there a little more that goes on with regards to checking certificates and the way the handshaking works as described [here](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/SSL-Certificates-HOWTO/x64.html).

Comment: Also, think about the fact that SSL is not a Java - specific protocol. In fact, I'd guess that some really large percentage of SSL connections in the real world are not created by Java code. So a .keystore file, which is Java-specific, by definition, could not be required by all SSL clients. It is just the public key that is shared.

Comment: The client does not 'respond encrypting a symmetric public key with the server's public key'. Both sides negotiate a symmetric session key and a shared pre-master secret via a key negotiation protocol documented in RFC 2246.

Answer (score 1):

**DEFINITELY NOT**

It would be a **major security breach** for two entities to be using the same private key and certificate. The private key is meant to be, err, private, and the certificate is intended to correspond to a unique identity that owns that private key. Any violation of that principle is a fundamental security error.